# Converting nested list (unequal length) to data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a nested list; for some indices, some variables are missing.

```
[[1]]
    sk   ques   pval 
  "10" "sfsf" "0.05" 

[[2]]
    sk   ques   pval   diff 
 "24" "wwww" "0.11"  "0.3" 

[[3]]
    sk   ques   pval   diff    imp 
  "24" "wwww" "0.11"  "0.3"    "2"
```

How can I convert this to data frame, where for the first row, data$diff[1] = NA?
Above case will be data frame with 5 variables and 3 observations.

The number of variables in the data frame will be number of unique names in list elements,
and missing values inside the list will be replaced with NA's.

Thank you,

EDIT : Data format

```
list(structure(c("10", "sfsf", "0.05"), .Names = c("sk", "ques", 
"pval")), structure(c("24", "wwww", "0.11", "0.3"), .Names = c("sk", 
"ques", "pval", "diff")), structure(c("24", "wwww", "0.11", "0.3", 
"2"), .Names = c("sk", "ques", "pval", "diff", "imp")))
```

Comment: Inside each list element, are those vectors or data frames?  They seem like named vectors.  Could you please post the output of `dput(head(list, 3))`

Comment: Good catch @RichardScriven. I had assumed they were proper data.frames. You can still use `rbind.fill` if you do the conversion: `rbind.fill(lapply(mydata, function(x)as.data.frame(t(x))))`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

We get the `length` of `list` element ('indx') by looping with `sapply`.  In the recent version of `R`, we can use `lengths` to replace the `sapply(.., length)` step.  We change the `length` of each element to the  `max` length from the 'indx' (`length<-`) and thereby pad `NA` values at the end of the `list` elements with length less than the `max` length.  We can `rbind` the `list` elements, convert to `data.frame` and change the column names.

```
 indx <- sapply(lst, length)
 #indx <- lengths(lst) 
 res <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,lapply(lst, `length<-`,
                          max(indx))))

 colnames(res) <- names(lst[[which.max(indx)]])
 res
 # sk ques pval diff  imp
 #1 10 sfsf 0.05 <NA> <NA>
 #2 24 wwww 0.11  0.3 <NA>
 #3 24 wwww 0.11  0.3    2
```

#### data

```
 lst <- list(structure(c("10", "sfsf", "0.05"), .Names = c("sk", "ques", 
 "pval")), structure(c("24", "wwww", "0.11", "0.3"), .Names = c("sk", 
 "ques", "pval", "diff")), structure(c("24", "wwww", "0.11", "0.3", 
 "2"), .Names = c("sk", "ques", "pval", "diff", "imp")))
```

Comment: When I try this solution, I get `Error in `row.names<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = value) : 
  duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed
In addition: Warning message:
non-unique value when setting 'row.names': ‘1’ `  at the point where `res` is defined. I'm not sure why that is happening.

Comment: @jessi If you are assigning duplicated row names to `data.frame` it will not work as `data.frame` can take only unique row names, but the duplicate row names for matrix is okay.i.e without the `as.data.frame`

Comment: @akrun, FYI tested this today, my resulting data frame is given colnames without calling `colnames(res) <- names(lst([[which.max(indx)]])`

Comment: @MartinSöderström  Based on the example in my post, before calling the last line of code, 'V4' and 'V5' are the column names for the 4th and 5th column which is changed with `colnames(res) <-`

Comment: @akrun What if it is nested list?                                                                   
    [[1]]
    sk   ques   pval [[act]]
  "10" "sfsf" "0.05" "time"

Comment: @Rudr You may need a nested lapply