# Extracting from Nested list to data frame

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I will put `dput` of what my list looks like at the bottom such that the q can be reproducible. The dput is of `a` not `x`.

I have a big nested list called `x` that I'm trying to build a data frame from but cannot figure it out.

I have done the first part:

```
for(i in 1:3){a[[i]]<-x$results[[i]]$experiences
indx <- lengths(a)
zz <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,lapply(a, `length<-`, max(indx))))}
```

For this I used the following answer:
[Converting nested list (unequal length) to data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27153979/converting-nested-list-unequal-length-to-data-frame)

This leaves me a data.frame with n columns for results where n is the max results for any i:

```
  v1   v2   v3
1 NULL NULL NULL
2  *    *    *
3 NULL NULL NULL
```

Each * is another nested list in the format `list(experience = list(duration = ...`

For example the first `*` in row 2, column v1. I don't want the total list. I only want:

```
a[[2]][[1]]$experience$start
```

or in terms of the original list x:

```
x$results[[2]]$experiences[[1]]$experience$start
```

I feel like I'm nearly there with some tweaks. I tried:

```
for(i in 1:3){a[[i]]<-x$results[[i]]$experiences
indx <- lengths(a)
for(y in 1:length(a[[i]])) aa <- rbind(aa,tryCatch(x$results[[i]]$experiences[[y]]$experience$start, error=function(e) print(NA)))
zz <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,lapply(aa, `length<-`, max(indx))))}
```

Resulting in:

```
  v1     v2     v3
1  NA     NA     NA
2  NA     NA     NA
3 2014    NA     NA
4 2012    NA     NA
5 2006    NA     NA
6  NA     NA     NA
7  NA     NA     NA
```

Tried cbind instead of rbind on final line and that put all the dates in the first row.

I also tried the following:

```
for(i in 1:3){a[[i]]<-lengths(x$results[[i]]$experiences)
  indx <- lengths(a)
for(y in 1:length(indx)){tt[i] <- tryCatch(x$results[[i]]$experiences[[y]]$experience$start, error=function(e) print(""))}
zz <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,lapply(tt, `length<-`, max(indx))))}
```

This came close, builds the right format but only returns the first result:

```
  v1   v2  v3
1 NA   NA  NA
2 2014 NA  NA
3 NA   NA  NA
```

The format I want is:

```
 V1  V2  V3
1 NA  NA  NA
2 2014 2012 2006
3 NA  NA  NA
```

((Sample data now at bottom))

Newest attempt:

Doing the following but returns only the first start date from each `a[[i]]`, the second loop I need to make the list `aa[i][y]` something different.

```
 for(i in 1:3){a[[i]]<-x$results[[i]]$experiences
 for(y in 1:length(a[[i]])){aa[i][y] = if(is.null(a[[i]][[y]]$experience$start)){"NULL"}else{a[[i]][[y]]$experience$start}}}
```

So for `dput2` I'd like the form:

```
  v1    v2  v3   v4   v5   v6   v7   v8
1 2015
2 2011 2007 null null null null null null
3 2016 2015 2015 2015 2013 2010
```

I dont mind if the blanks are null or na

UPDATE

The below answer almost works, however in my data the structure changes, the order of the names (roleName, duration etc) change so that ruins the answer as `cumsum` is used to determine when a new list is found. If you have `duration` then `start` the keys are `9` and `1` and the `cumsum` part labels them two different lists.

I wrote the following:

```
my.list <- list(structure(
  list(
    experience = structure(
      list(
        start = "1",
        end = "1",
        roleName = "a",
        summary = "a",
        duration = "a",
        current = "a",
        org = structure(list(name = "a", url = "a"), .Names = c("name","url")),
        location = structure(
          list(
            displayLocation = NULL,
            lat = NULL,
            lng = NULL
          ),
          .Names = c("displayLocation",
                     "lat", "lng")
        ) ),.Names = c("start", "end", "roleName", "summary", "duration", "current", "org", "location")),
    `_meta` = structure(
      list(weight = 1L, `_sources` = list(structure(
        list(`_origin` = "a"), .Names = "_origin"
      ))),.Names = c("weight", "_sources"))),.Names = c("experience", "_meta")))
```

Then:

```
aa <- lapply(1:length(a), function(y){tryCatch(lapply(1:length(a[[y]]), 
                     function(i){a[[y]][[i]]$experience[names(my.list2[[1]]$experience)]}), error=function(e) print(list()))})
```

This changes the structure such that `key2` will always be in the right order.

However Then I found after this loop I have another issue.

Sometimes I have for example nothing but a roleName in the experience list. If that occurs twice in a row the keys are repeated. `cumsum` treats them as the same experience instead of separate ones.

This means I cannot create `df3` because of duplicate identifiers for rows. And even if I could by removing troublesome rows, the names wouldn't match as `i` in the solution below matches the names using the sequence, if I remove any rows that changes the lengths.

Here is my total code for more insight:

```
for(i in 1:x$count){a[[i]]<-x$results[[i]]$experiences}

  aa <- lapply(1:length(a), function(y){tryCatch(lapply(1:length(a[[y]]), 
                     function(i){a[[y]][[i]]$experience[names(my.list2[[1]]$experience)]}), error=function(e) print(list()))})

  aaa <- unlist(aa)
  dummydf <- data.frame(b=c("start", "end", "roleName", "summary", 
                            "duration", "current", "org.name",  "org.url"), key=1:8)

  df <- data.frame(a=aaa, b=names(aaa))
  df2 <- left_join(df, dummydf)
  df2$key2 <- as.factor(cumsum(df2$key < c(0, df2$key[-length(df2$key)])) +1)

  df_split <- split(df2, df2$key2)
  df3 <- lapply(df_split, function(x){
    x %>% select(-c(key, key2)) %>% spread(b, a)
  }) %>% data.table::rbindlist(fill=TRUE) %>% t
  df3 <- data.frame(df3)
  i <- sapply(seq_along(aa), function(y) rep(y, sapply(aa, function(x) length(x))[y])) %>% unlist
  names(df3) <- paste0(names(df3), "_", i)
  df4 <- data.frame(t(df3))
  df4$dates <- as.Date(NA)
  df4$dates <- as.Date(df4$start)
  df4 <- data.frame(dates = df4$dates)
  df4 <- t(df4)
  df4 <- data.frame(df4)
  names(df4) <- paste0(names(df4), "_", i)
  df4[] <- lapply(df4[], as.character)
  l1 <- lapply(split(stack(df4), sub('.*_', '', stack(df4)[,2])), '[', 1)
  df5 <- t(do.call(cbindPad, l1))
  df5 <- data.frame(df5)
```

`cbindpad` taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6988184/combining-two-data-frames-of-different-lengths)

New sample code including the issues:

```
dput3 = 
list(list(), list(
structure(list(experience = structure(list(
  duration = "1", start = "2014", 
  end = "3000", roleName = "a", 
  summary = "aaa", 
  org = structure(list(name = "a"), .Names = "name"), 
  location = structure(list(displayLocation = NULL, lat = NULL, 
    lng = NULL), .Names = c("displayLocation", "lat", "lng"
    ))), .Names = c("duration", "start", "end", "roleName", "summary", 
    "org", "location")), `_meta` = structure(list(weight = 1L, `_sources` = list(
      structure(list(`_origin` = ""), .Names = "_origin"))), .Names = c("weight", 
      "_sources"))), .Names = c("experience", "_meta")), 
structure(list(
        experience = structure(list(end = "3000", 
        start = "2012", duration = "2", 
        roleName = "a", summary = "aaa", 
        org = structure(list(name = "None"), .Names = "name"), 
        location = structure(list(displayLocation = NULL, lat = NULL, lng = NULL), .Names = c("displayLocation", "lat", "lng"))), .Names = c("duration", "start", "end", "roleName", 
        "summary", "org", "location")), `_meta` = structure(list(
          weight = 1L, `_sources` = list(structure(list(`_origin` = " "), .Names = "_origin"))), .Names = c("weight", "_sources"))), .Names = c("experience", "_meta")), 
  structure(list(
            experience = structure(list(duration = "3", 
            start = "2006", end = "3000", 
            roleName = "a", summary = "aaa", org = structure(list(name = " "), .Names = "name"), 
            location = structure(list(displayLocation = NULL, lat = NULL, lng = NULL), .Names = c("displayLocation", "lat", "lng"))), .Names = c("duration", "start", "end", "roleName",
            "summary", "org", "location")), `_meta` = structure(list(weight = 1L, `_sources` = list(structure(list(`_origin` = ""), .Names = "_origin"))), .Names = c("weight", 
            "_sources"))), .Names = c("experience", "_meta")),
  structure(list(
            experience = structure(list(roleName = "a",  
            location = structure(list(displayLocation = NULL, lat = NULL, lng = NULL), .Names = c("displayLocation", "lat", "lng"))), .Names = c("roleName", 
           "location")), `_meta` = structure(list(
            weight = 1L, `_sources` = list(structure(list(`_origin` = " "), .Names = "_origin"))), .Names = c("weight", "_sources"))), .Names = c("experience", "_meta")),
structure(list(
            experience = structure(list(roleName = "a",  
            location = structure(list(displayLocation = NULL, lat = NULL, lng = NULL), .Names = c("displayLocation", "lat", "lng"))), .Names = c("roleName", 
            "location")), `_meta` = structure(list(
            weight = 1L, `_sources` = list(structure(list(`_origin` = " "), .Names = "_origin"))), .Names = c("weight", "_sources"))), .Names = c("experience", "_meta"))
            ), 
            list(
structure(list(experience = structure(list(
              duration = "1", start = "2014", 
              end = "3000", roleName = "a", 
              summary = "aaa", 
              org = structure(list(name = "a"), .Names = "name"), 
              location = structure(list(displayLocation = NULL, lat = NULL, 
                lng = NULL), .Names = c("displayLocation", "lat", "lng"
                ))), .Names = c("duration", "start", "end", "roleName", "summary", 
                "org", "location")), `_meta` = structure(list(weight = 1L, `_sources` = list(
                  structure(list(`_origin` = ""), .Names = "_origin"))), .Names = c("weight", 
                  "_sources"))), .Names = c("experience", "_meta"))))
```

Comment: I am having trouble relating your expected output to the dput you provided. Where are those dates?

Comment: Could you do it by editing it to your question? It is important that your example matches your expected output especially for such complicated operations

Comment: dput now far more usable

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

a <- unlist(a)

df <- data.frame(a=a, b=names(a)) %>% mutate(key=cumsum(b=="experience.duration")) %>% 
      split(.$key) %>% lapply(function(x) x %>% select(-key) %>% spread(b, a)) %>% 
      do.call(rbind, .) %>% t %>% data.frame

df$key <- rownames(df)
```

Then you can filter in on the rows of interest

The above would be equivalent to

```
rbind(unlist(a)[1:8], unlist(a)[9:16],unlist(a)[17:24]) %>% t
```

### Update

try this for `dput2`

```
a <- unlist(dput2)

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dummydf <- data.frame(b=c("experience.start", "experience.end", "experience.roleName", "experience.summary", 
                      "experience.org", "experience.org.name",  "experience.org.url", 
                      "_meta.weight", "_meta._sources._origin", "experience.duration"), key=1:10)


df <- data.frame(a=a, b=names(a))

df2 <- left_join(df, dummydf)
df2$key2 <- as.factor(cumsum(df2$key < c(0, df2$key[-length(df2$key)])) +1)
df_split <- split(df2, df2$key2)
df3 <- lapply(df_split, function(x){
       x %>% select(-c(key, key2)) %>% spread(b, a)
       }) %>% data.table::rbindlist(fill=TRUE) %>% t

df3 <- data.frame(df3)
i <- sapply(seq_along(dput2), function(y) rep(y, sapply(dput2, function(x) length(x))[y])) %>% unlist
names(df3) <- paste0(names(df3), "_", i)

View(df3)
```

Comment: try to share a `dput` as "representative" as possible.

Comment: @Olivia I have updated it. It works for the specified `dplut2`

Comment: You cannot have duplicate column names.

Comment: I have the following column names `x#_y` where `y` is the list the data was in.

Comment: I didn;t specify but yes the order of the `dummydf` has to preset to match the order within your list.

Comment: @Olivia i will try to look at it over the next few days

Answer (score 0):

Managed to figure something out, using `dput3` above:

```
a <- dput3

aa <- lapply(1:length(a), function(y){tryCatch(lapply(1:length(a[[y]]), 
  function(i){if(is.null(a[[y]][[i]]$experience$start)){"Null"}else{a[[y]][[i]]$experience$start}}),error=function(e) print(list()))})


for(i in 1:length(aa)){for(y in 1:length(aa[[i]])){tryCatch(for(z in length(aa[[i]][[y]]))
     {test <- rbind(test, data.frame(key = i, key2= y))},error=function(e) print(0))}}

aaa <- unlist(aa)
df <- data.frame(a=aaa)
df2 <- cbind(df, test)
i <- sapply(seq_along(aa), function(y) rep(y, sapply(aa, function(x) length(x))[y])) %>% unlist

df5 <- data.frame(dates = df2$a)
df5 <- t(df5)
df5 <- data.frame(df5)
names(df5) <- paste0(names(df5), "_", i)
df5[] <- lapply(df5[], as.character)
l1 <- lapply(split(stack(df5), as.numeric(sub('.*_', '', stack(df5)[,2]))), '[', 1)
df6 <- t(do.call(cbindPad, l1))
df6 <- data.frame(df6)
```

Will try and expand it so it works with more than one vertical (as currently in `aa` I isolate `start`)