# Transforming data frame using column name

Tags: r, dataframe, transform

This is following on from another question 
[Extracting from Nested list to data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41466883/extracting-from-nested-list-to-data-frame/41471467?noredirect=1#comment70178131_41471467)

Using the updated answer I get my data frame I will start with.

I then use `df <- data.frame(start = df3[5,])`

So I'm left with:

```
dput(df)
structure(list(start.X1_1 = structure(4L, .Names = "experience.start", .Label = c("", 
" ", "1", "2015"), class = "factor"), start.X2_2 = structure(3L, .Names = "experience.start", .Label = c(" ", 
"1", "2011"), class = "factor"), start.X3_2 = structure(3L, .Names = "experience.start", .Label = c(" ", 
"1", "2007"), class = "factor"), start.X4_2 = structure(NA_integer_, .Names = "experience.start", .Label = c(" ", 
"1"), class = "factor"), start.X5_2 = structure(NA_integer_, .Names = "experience.start", .Label = c(" ", 
"1"), class = "factor"), start.X6_2 = structure(NA_integer_, .Names = "experience.start", .Label = c(" ", 
"1"), class = "factor"), start.X7_2 = structure(NA_integer_, .Names = "experience.start", .Label = c(" ", 
"1"), class = "factor"), start.X8_2 = structure(NA_integer_, .Names = "experience.start", .Label = c(" ", 
"1"), class = "factor"), start.X9_2 = structure(NA_integer_, .Names = "experience.start", .Label = c(" ", 
"1"), class = "factor"), start.X10_3 = structure(3L, .Names = "experience.start", .Label = c(" ", 
"1", "2016", "3000"), class = "factor"), start.X11_3 = structure(3L, .Names = "experience.start", .Label = c(" ", 
"1", "2015", "3000"), class = "factor"), start.X12_3 = structure(4L, .Names = "experience.start", .Label = c("", 
" ", "1", "2015", "2016", "EE"), class = "factor"), start.X13_3 = structure(4L, .Names = "experience.start", .Label = c("", 
" ", "1", "2014", "2015"), class = "factor"), start.X14_3 = structure(3L, .Names = "experience.start", .Label = c(" ", 
"1", "2013", "2014"), class = "factor"), start.X15_3 = structure(3L, .Names = "experience.start", .Label = c(" ", 
"1", "2010", "2011", "Virtusa"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("start.X1_1", 
"start.X2_2", "start.X3_2", "start.X4_2", "start.X5_2", "start.X6_2", 
"start.X7_2", "start.X8_2", "start.X9_2", "start.X10_3", "start.X11_3", 
"start.X12_3", "start.X13_3", "start.X14_3", "start.X15_3"), row.names = "experience.start", class = "data.frame")
```

Now I'd like to get to the format:

```
  v1    v2  v3   v4   v5   v6   v7   v8
1 2015
2 2011 2007 null null null null null null
3 2016 2015 2015 2015 2013 2010
```

I can use the following to find the columns that match

```
sR <- function(x, n){
    substr(x, nchar(x)-n+1, nchar(x))}

 sR(names(df),2)
 [1] "_1" "_2" "_2" "_2" "_2" "_2" "_2" "_2" "_2" "_3" "_3" "_3" "_3" "_3" "_3"
```

So I think from here there must be a way I can get to my desired output.

Or I'm sure someone will show me a better way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main idea is to `split` your data frame based on the suffix after the underscore. This way you get a list with 3 elements, 1 for each suffix (in your case `1`, `2`, `3`)

```
df[] <- lapply(df[], as.character)
l1 <- lapply(split(stack(df), as.numeric(sub('.*_', '', stack(df)[,2]))), '[', 1)
lapply(l1, head, 2)

#$`1`
#  values
#1   2015

#$`2`
#  values
#2   2011
#3   2007

#$`3`
#   values
#10   2016
#11   2015
```

Now all we need to do is `cbind` those 3 elements together which is a bit tricky since their length is different. Luckily there are great answers here in SO which we can use (see disclaimer below) that take care of that problem.

```
t(do.call(cbindPad, l1))

#       1      2      3      4      5      6      7  8 
#values "2015" NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA NA
#values "2011" "2007" NA     NA     NA     NA     NA NA
#values "2016" "2015" "2015" "2014" "2013" "2010" NA NA
```

**DISCLAIMER**

The function `cbindPad` was taken from @Joran's answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6988184/combining-two-data-frames-of-different-lengths)

Alternatively, there is the function `rbind.fill` in `plyr` package which can be used after transposing to give a sort of `cbind.fill` result.

```
plyr::rbind.fill(lapply(l1, function(i) as.data.frame(t(i))))

#     1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15
#1 2015 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
#2 <NA> 2011 2007 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
#3 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> 2016 2015 2015 2014 2013 2010
```

Comment: I cant do the first line: Error in stack.data.frame(df) : no vector columns were selected

Comment: Oh you have to convert to character. I ll add it

Comment: anyway you can explain your answer, I need to reasearch split and stack but I dont like using answers without understanding whats happening. Thanks again

Comment: Edited my answer. Let me know if you need any further clarifications

Comment: There is no problem.  It just got me reminded about that function.  Anyway pluse one

Comment: @Olivia the `'[', 1` part is for taking the first column only because `stack` gives a column with values and a column with column names.

Comment: @akrun it comes up quite often. Not only here in SO, but I found myself using it quite a bit at my job

Comment: Good to know that it is a useful function

Comment: Where can I read up on using '[' , n (where n is number of columns) like that . I've never seen that before

Comment: just type `?`[`` in your session

Comment: Note I had to put as.numeric around the sub part otherwise 100 comes after 1 and all the numbering order is thrown out

Comment: You are right. Should have wrapped it in `as.numeric`